# Erlang failing to connect to mysql/mariadb

Tags: mysql, erlang, mariadb, erlang-shell

I cannot connect to mysql/mariadb with erlang.

The requirements according to this github-page:
https://github.com/mysql-otp/mysql-otp

Requirements:

```
Erlang/OTP version R16B or later
MySQL database version 4.1 or later or MariaDB
GNU Make or Rebar or any other tool for building Erlang/OTP applications
```

Version:

```
14> erlang:system_info(otp_release).
"22"
```

I'm not sure if this requirement is needed anymore but I added this:

`[mysqld] default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password`

to my /etc/my.cnf. But this is probably irrelevant since the error is an undefined function.
I can compile the code but I cannot run it. Any help to get this working is much appreciated.

The code:

```
-module(mydatabase).
-compile(export_all).

connect_to_database() -> 
Conn = mysql:start_link([{host, "localhost"}, {user, "user"},
                       {password, "password"}, {database, "MyDatabase"}]) ,
           
  case Conn of
      {ok, Pid} -> io:fwrite("~w~w~n", [ok,Pid]);
      {error, ConnErr}  -> io:fwrite("error : ~p ~n", [ConnErr])
    end.
              
 start() -> connect_to_database().
```

mariadb is running:

```
sudo systemctl status mariadb
[sudo] password for user: 
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.4.13 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; disabled; vendor >
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-06-28 15:33:50 CEST; 1h 4min ago
```

The error message:

```
12> c(mydatabase).     
mydatabase.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,mydatabase}
13> mydatabase:start().
** exception error: undefined function mysql:start_link/1
 in function  mydatabase:connect_to_database/0 (mydatabase.erl, line 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot about this requirement:

> GNU Make or Rebar or any other tool for building Erlang/OTP applications

According to the [mysql-otp docs](https://github.com/mysql-otp/mysql-otp):

> MySQL/OTP is a driver for connecting Erlang/OTP applications to MySQL
> and MariaDB databases.

An `OTP application` requires a certain architecture, and the mysql driver needs to be listed as a dependency in the application.  Your error is due to the fact that there is no function named `mysql:start_link/1` in Erlang.  Rather, that's a third party function that your code has to somehow access, hence the [Usage as a Dependency](https://github.com/mysql-otp/mysql-otp#usage-as-a-dependency) section in the docs.

The following steps can be used to create an `OTP application` which employs mysql/mariaDB as a dependency:

1. [Install rebar3](https://www.rebar3.org/docs/getting-started).
2. Create a rebar3 `app`:

   ```
   ~/erlang_programs/mysql1$ rebar3 new app myapp
   ===> Writing myapp/src/myapp_app.erl
   ===> Writing myapp/src/myapp_sup.erl
   ===> Writing myapp/src/myapp.app.src
   ===> Writing myapp/rebar.config
   ===> Writing myapp/.gitignore
   ===> Writing myapp/LICENSE
   ===> Writing myapp/README.md
   ```
3. Add mysql-otp as a dependency in the rebar.config file:

   ```
     ~/erlang_programs/mysql1$ cd myapp
     ~/erlang_programs/mysql1/myapp$ ls
     LICENSE       rebar.config
     README.md src
   ```

like this:

```
    {erl_opts, [debug_info]}.
    {deps, [

      {mysql, ".*", {
                      git, "https://github.com/mysql-otp/mysql-otp",
                      {tag, "1.6.0"}
                    }
      }

    ]}.

    {shell, [
      % {config, "config/sys.config"},
        {apps, [myapp]}
    ]}.
```

4. Put your source code in the `src` directory:

   ```
    ~/erlang_programs/mysql1/myapp$ cd src
    ~/erlang_programs/mysql1/myapp/src$ ls
    my_mysql.erl    myapp_app.erl
    myapp.app.src   myapp_sup.erl
   ```

my_mysql.erl:

```
-module(my_mysql).
-compile(export_all).

do_mysql(Name, Info) ->
    {ok, MysqlPid} = mysql:start_link(
                  [{host, "localhost"}, 
                   {user, "root"},
                   {password, ""}, 
                   {database, "mydb"}
                  ]
                ),

     ok = mysql:query(
           MysqlPid, 
           "INSERT INTO people (name, info) VALUES (?, ?)", [Name, Info]
        ),

     {ok, ColumnNames, Rows} = mysql:query(
                MysqlPid, 
                <<"SELECT * FROM people">>),

     io:format("ColumnNames: ~p~nRows: ~p~n", [ColumnNames, Rows]).
```

5. Fetch the dependencies and compile all the source code:

   ```
    ~/erlang_programs/mysql1/myapp$ rebar3 compile
    ===> Verifying dependencies...
    ===> Fetching mysql ({git,"https://github.com/mysql-otp/mysql-otp",
                                     {tag,"1.6.0"}})
    ===> Compiling mysql
    ===> Compiling myapp
    src/my_mysql.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
   ```
6. Launch the shell and automatically construct paths to all your .beam files (in the deeply nested directories that rebar3 puts them):

   ```
    ~/erlang_programs/mysql1/myapp$ rebar3 shell
    ===> Verifying dependencies...
    ===> Compiling myapp
    Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

    ===> The rebar3 shell is a development tool; to deploy applications in production, consider using releases (http://www.rebar3.org/docs/releases)
    ===> Booted myapp
    Eshell V9.3  (abort with ^G)
   ```
7. Execute your function:

   ```
    1> my_mysql:do_mysql("Jeffsy", "2.0").
    ColumnNames: [<<"id">>,<<"name">>,<<"info">>]
    Rows: [[1,<<"7stud">>,<<"abc">>],
           [2,<<"Beth">>,<<"xxx">>],
           [3,<<"Diane">>,<<"xyz">>],
           [4,<<"Kathy">>,<<"xyz">>],
           [5,<<"Kathy">>,<<"xyz">>],
           [6,<<"Dave">>,<<"efg">>],
           [7,<<"Tom">>,<<"zzz">>],
           [8,<<"David">>,<<"abc">>],
           [9,<<"Eloise">>,<<"abc">>],
           [10,<<"Jess">>,<<"xyz">>],
           [11,<<"Jeffsy">>,<<"2.0">>]]
    ok
   ```